# Git log - GitlabCI - saving to file with variable in name from git log

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

in gitlab.ci.yml - ill trying to check gitlog on commits messages after last tag, and its worked:

```
$ git log  --oneline -- "instruction/1.0/" $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 @^)
00:00
5cee88f Add new file - new instruction
26f5e26 Added new blablabla
```

when i try to save result in file, its still work fine, we have test.log in folder

```
   git log  --oneline -- "instruction/1.0/" $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 @^) > test.log
   ls
   test.log
```

but if we try to include CI var in file name, we dont have any result ($SYSTEM_NAME used in this playbook in other modules and everything is ok)

```
git log  --oneline -- "instruction/1.0/" $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 @^) > $SYSTEM_NAME.log
```

is it any other methods to use dynamically filename in gitlog output?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's thinking that the `.log` at the end of `$SYSTEM_NAME` is part of the variable, not an extension after it evaluates the variable. Try separating the variable from the string like this:
`${SYSTEM_NAME}.log`